# Afnetworking Json Login with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, afnetworking

I'm trying work with webservice.And I'm posting username and password with afnetworking.I'm getting this output.It's Ok.But I need the use it with coreData.And how can I keep session in application.

What should I do in this case.

```
GET: {"result":"active","id":"11","name":"John App","statu":"customer","token":"VE0HRuf33fv6y7lIftJYJVfFtmwaRN"}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to parse response to NSDictionary using
   NSJsonSerialization
2. Than you can extract your values using key-value access in
   NSDictionary
3. Setup and create core data model (.xcdatamodel file)
4. You can use some tools like MagicalRecord for simplify your life
   with core data
5. write to data base and save object.

Comment: @Murat - what are you trying to convey?